# What happened to my code that makes replit.com crash?

Tags: javascript

So bascially whenever I run my code, it takes for ever and makes replit.com unresponsive. When I comment out all my javascript it works and it doesn't run forever. Usually it would tell me in the console that I had a problem like I put to many parentheses or it had an unexpected string. But I've never had my code be so messed up that it crash replit.com. Is there something thats going on forever and ever in my code? I know that its not replit.com because I tested on another repl and that repl worked. btw heres my code

Edit: So I did more experimenting, and when I take away the pictures it loads, just without the pictures obvioulsy. When I added the picture back again it doesn't work. The pictures used to work so I think that its the display.updateUpgrades. I should've also prefaced that after I put the display.updateUpgrades is when it stopped working

```
let game = {
  score: 0,
  totalScore: 0,
  totalClicks: 0,
  clickValue: 1,
  version: 0.000,

  addToScore: function (amount) {

    this.score += amount;
    this.totalScore += amount;
    display.updateScore();

  },

  getScorePerSecond: function () {
    var scorePerSecond = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < building.name.length; i++) {
      scorePerSecond += building.income[i] * building.count[i]
    }
    return scorePerSecond
  }
};

let building = {
  name: [
    "miningLevel",
    "Miners",
    "Mining Warehouse",
    "Hackers"
  ],
  image: [
    "pickaxe.png",
    "miner.png",
    "MiningWarehouse.jpeg",
    "Hacker.jpg"

  ],
  count: [0, 0, 0, 0],
  income: [
    10,
    20,
    30,
    40
  ],
  cost: [
    25,
    100,
    500,
    1000
  ],

  purchase: function (index) {
    if (game.score >= this.cost[index]) {
      game.score -= this.cost[index];
      this.count[index]++;
      this.cost[index] = Math.ceil(this.cost[index] * 1.10);
      display.updateScore();
      display.updateShop();
      display.updateUpgrades();
    }
  }
}

let upgrade = {
    name : [
      "Better Picks"
    ],
    description: [
      "Picks mine twice the amount of bitcoin"
    ],
    image:[
      "goldPickaxe.png"
    ],
    type: [
      "building"
    ],
    cost: [
      1000
    ],
    buildingIndex: [
      0
    ],
    requirement: [
      10
    ],
    bonus: [
      2
    ],
    purchased:[false],
     
    purchase: function (index) {
    if(!this.purchased[index] && game.score >= this.cost[index]) {
      if (this.type[index] == "building" && building.count[this.buildingIndex[index]] >= this.requirement[index]) {
       game.score -= this.cost[index];
       building.income[this.buidlingIndex[index] *= this.bonus[index]];
       this.purchased[index] = true;
      
      display.updateUpgrades();
      display.updateScore(); 
      
      } else if (this.type[index] == "click" && game.totalClicks >= this.requirement[index]) {
      game.score -= this.cost[index];
       game.clickValue *= this.bonus[index];
       this.purchased[index] = true;
      
      display.updateUpgrades();
      display.updateScore();
      }
    }
  }
};



var display = {
  updateScore: function () {
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = game.score;
    document.getElementById("scorepersecond").innerHTML = game.getScorePerSecond()
    document.title = "Bitcoin Simulator"
  },
  updateShop: function () {
    document.getElementById("shopContainer").innerHTML = " ";

    for (var i = 0; i < building.name.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById("shopContainer").innerHTML += '<table class="shopButton unselectable" onclick="building.purchase('+i+')"><tr><td id"image"><img src="'+building.image[i]+'"></td> <td id="nameAndCost"> <p>'+building.name[i]+'</p> <p><span>'+building.cost[i]+'</span> Bitcoin</p> </td> <td id="amount"><span>'+building.count[i]+'<span></td></tr> </table>';
    }
  },
  updateUpgrades: function() {
    document.getElementById("upgradeContainer").innerHTML = " ";
    for (var i = 0; i < upgrade.name.length; i++) {
      if (!upgrade.purchased[i]) {
        if (upgrade.type[i] == "building" && building.count[upgrade.buildingIndex[i]] >= upgrade.requirement[i]) {
          document.getElementById("upgradeContainer").innerHTML += '<img src="'+upgrade.image[i]+'" title="'+upgrade.name[i]+' &#10;'+upgrade.description+' $#10; ('+upgrade.cost[i]+' bitcoin)" onclick="upgrade.purchase('+i+')">';

        } else if (upgrade.type[i] == "click" && game.totalClicks >= upgrade.requirement[index]){
           document.getElementById("upgradeContainer").innerHTML += '<img src="'+upgrade.image[i]+'" title="'+upgrade.name[i]+' &#10;'+upgrade.description+' $#10;('+upgrade.cost[i]+' bitcoin)" onclick="upgrade.purchase('+i+')">';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}



function saveGame() {
  var gameSave = {
    score: game.score,
    totalScore: game.totalScore,
    totalClicks: game.totalClicks,
    clickValue: game.clickValue,
    version: game.version,
    buildingCount: building.count,
    buildingIncome: building.income,
    buildingCost: building.cost,
    upgradePurchased: upgrade.purchased

  };
  localStorage.setItem("gameSave", JSON.stringify(gameSave))
}

function loadGame() {
  let savedGame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("gameSave")); 
  if (localStorage.getItem("gameSave") !== null) {

    if (typeof savedGame.score !== "undefined") game.score = savedGame.score;

    if (typeof savedGame.totalScore !== "undefined") game.totalScore = savedGame.totalScore;

    if (typeof savedGame.totalClicks !== "undefined") game.totalClicks = savedGame.totalClicks;

    if (typeof savedGame.clickValue !== "undefined") game.clickValue = savedGame.clickValue;
    
    if(typeof savedGame.buildingCount !== "undefined") {
      for( var i = 0; i < savedGame.buildingCount.length; i++) {
        building.count[i] = savedGame.buildingCount[i];
      }
    }

        if (typeof savedGame.buildingIncome !== "undefined") {
          for (var i = 0; i < savedGame.buildingIncome.length; i++) {
            building.income[i] = savedGame.buildingIncome[i];
         
            if (typeof savedGame.buildingCost !== "undefined") {
              for (var i = 0; i < savedGame.buildingCost.length; i++) {
                building.cost[i] = savedGame.buildingCost[i]
              }
            }
            if(typeof savedGame.upgradePurchased !== "undefined") {
              for (var i = 0; i < savedGame.upgradePurchased.length; i++) {
                upgrade.purchase[i] = savedGame.upgradePurchased[i];
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    function resetGame() {
      if (confirm("Are you sure you want to reset your game")) {
        let gameSave = { }
        localStorage.setItem("gameSave", JSON.stringify(gameSave));
        location.reload();
      }
    }

    document.getElementById("clicker").addEventListener("click", function() {
       game.totalClicks++;
       game.addToScore(game.clickValue + building.count[0])
    }, false)


    window.onload = function () {
      loadGame();
      display.updateScore();
      display.updateUpgrades();
      display.updateShop();
    };

    setInterval(function () {
      game.score += game.getScorePerSecond();
      game.totalScore += game.getScorePerSecond();
      display.updateScore();
    }, 1000)

setInterval(function() {
  display.updateScore();
  display.updateUpgrades();
},10000) 



    setInterval(function () {
      saveGame();
    }, 3000);


document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.which == 83) {
    event.preventDefault();
    saveGame();
  }
}, false);
```

Sry its 200 lines.

Comment: Does it work locally? Does it crash?

Comment: @PyxlDavon what do you mean locally? Edit: if you mean like use notepad I can't because I'm using a Chromebook

Comment: Does chromebook not have any sort of local server? Because that'd be pretty incredible.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans idk what you mean by local server, but chromebooks don't have anything like notepad

Comment: why would you want notepad when [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2020/12/03/chromebook-get-started) runs on a chromebook just fine?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't have VS code, and even if I did it probably won't work. Its not a problem with repl, its a problem in the code. And you can open teh website on a different tab with repl anyways

Comment: If you're unwilling to install an editor that lets you test your code locally, on your own computer, instead of a website that happens to let you live code, at the very least run through the [mcve] exercise: start reducing your code until it _does_ run (even if it no longer does everything). You're problem solving, so first: find the actual problem. And for that, you don't need SO yet.

Answer (score -1):

So what happened was that one of my if functions were in an if function even though it wasn't supposed to be in that if function. Everything is working fine now

Comment: Then it sounds like you solved your own problem, with only a few hours of debugging at most: worth deleting your question again.